# Use specific Node version in combination with specific npm version

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, node-modules, nvm

For a client's web project I work with two other developers. The frontend is built with quite a setup (gulp, foundation, bower, ...) and started a few years ago. They both use a (never updated)

> combination of **Node v6.12.2 and npm v5.6.0**.

As I had Node v10.x on my machine and the first attempts of running `npm install` after cloning the project failed, I'd like to use the exact same setup:

I setup nvm to use v6.12.2

```
$ \projectfolder nvm use v6.12.2
```

The Terminal then states:

```
Now using node v6.12.2 (npm v3.10.10)
```

How can I tell my setup to use npm@5.6.0 along with node v6.12.2? I tried `npm install npm@5.6.0` which then changes the used npm version, but also changes the used node version back.

I know nvm installs the respective npm version along with the node version. But is there a way to work with **exactly this combination of versions** the other developers use in my project?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After switching `node` versions with `nvm use` (and confirming you switched with `node --version`), you should **globally** update/downgrade `npm` with:

```js
npm install -g npm@5.6.0 // -g arg is important
```

Switch back to other node version and it should be using its own version. Also see this [npm article](https://www.npmjs.com/get-npm) about installing npm versions.

If you want to know why it is installed globally: run in the command line:

```
ls -l $(which npm)
```

It returns

```
/home/USER_NAME/.nvm/versions/node/vNODE_VERSION/bin/npm -> ../lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
```

It's a symlink to the global `node_modules` folder of that specific node version.

Comment: Thank you very much, the -g flag did the job and now I can work with the "desired" setup! Now if I switch to v10.2.1 by saying `nvm use 10.2.1`: I  understand I could also now install the latest version of npm using `npm install -g latest-version` and it would be "related" to v10.2.1 via symlink - while 5.6.0 would still remain the used version by 6.12.2? I guess I will just try, I'm just so happy it worked :-) Thanks again

Comment: Yes, although the correct syntax is `npm install -g npm@latest`. It is possible. It's exactly the reason why version managers like `nvm` are so wonderful.

Answer (score 1):

Find where your nvm is installed .eg:

[image]

Then you can explicitly call your desired npm version like:

```
your\path\..\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v12.10.0\npm -help
```